# FFMPEG: Convert video to Animated Gif Preview getting frame after interval

Tags: video, ffmpeg, gif, animated-gif

I would like to generate a gif preview for my application and made it on my server using FFMPEG.

It should generate a gif getting 10 frames for each video but without using a temp dir(or temp files relating each frame) if it's possible.

Regarding this answer on [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/556029/how-do-i-convert-a-video-to-gif-using-ffmpeg-with-reasonable-quality), it should generate a gif using each frame, this is not I need.

Seems to be strange but the effect I need is something you can see on many porn websites (I don't remember what of these)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, [this article on FFmpeg's Wiki named "Create a thumbnail image every X seconds of the video"](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video) shows that FFmpeg can't do what you want it to do (without some automated calculations).

The wiki says that `-vf "fps=fps=XYZ"` is your best shot - it will create one thumbnail/frame every `XYZ` frames of the original video. If you really want 10 pictures per video and they all have different lengths, you could first read out the total frame-count and then calculate the needed fps with a script:

```
XYZ=wanted_frames_times_actual_fps/total_frames_of_vid
```

with `wanted_frames_times_actual_fps` being e.g. `10*25` (PAL) or `10*30` (NTSC) in your case and `total_frames_of_vid=(hh*3600+mm*60+ss)*25+ff`, where `hh` means hours, `mm` means minutes, `ss` means seconds, and `ff` means frames (after the last counted second). *Calculation example: a timecode of `01:35:45:24` (or `01:35:45.960` in FFmpeg's terms, as FFmpeg doesn't use frames but milliseconds) at 25 frames per second resembles 143649 frames total.*

This solution could well work - you just need to find a way to get the total time of the video (e.g. via ffprobe) and its fps (if you can't get a proper timecode) and then store that info as a variable named `$total_frames_of_vid`.

---

I found another approach on this in the Wiki's "Also see"-section, linking to 
[a superuser-question named "Meaningful thumbnails for a Video using FFmpeg"](https://superuser.com/questions/538112/meaningful-thumbnails-for-a-video-using-ffmpeg) which suggests using:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -i <YOUR_VIDEO> -vf "select=gt(scene\,0.8)" -frames:v 10 -vsync vfr -vf "fps=fps=1/200" -y out%03d.png
```

<sub>(I modified the code a bit - changed image codec to PNG and changed values for `-frames:v` and `fps`. Also changed the output images to have three digits in their names.)</sub>

and then re-coding them to your GIF.

This solution also needs some computation or manual labor, as the values of all options (and especially `fps` need changing according to the length of the video. I.e. I tried the original code from superuser with a 35min video - and only got 5 frames out of it.