# Convert mp4 to mp3 with ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, media

I want to convert a whole folder of mp4 files to mp3. But I have no idea how to do that?  But I want to keep the thumbnail. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Sure! Please click on [edit] and post the code you've tried so far which did not work. Please use [edit] and not Add Comment.

Comment: This breaks down into setting up a loop (for Linux:) https://www.shellscript.sh/loops.html  which, for each MP4 file, will A) extract the thumbnail https://superuser.com/questions/538112/meaningful-thumbnails-for-a-video-using-ffmpeg B) extract the audio into an MP3 https://mutsinzi.com/alternative-to-pacpl-mp4-to-mp3-converter/ and C) add the thumbnail into the MP3.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18710992/how-to-add-album-art-with-ffmpeg

Comment: What is your OS?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to do this in three steps:

```
ffmpeg -vn -sn -dn -i input.mp4 -codec:a libmp3lame -qscale:a 4 output.mp3
```

This creates a MP3 file with a VBR (variable bit rate) of 165. Check [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/MP3) for more options.

Arguments (**beware**, the order matters!):

- `-vn` disables all video-streams from the input
- `-sn` disables all subtitle-streams from the input
- `-dn` disables all data-streams from the input
- `-i` specifies the input file
- `-codec:a libmp3lame` specifies the encoder
- `-qscale:a 4` specifies the quality target for libmp3lame
- The last argument is the output-file. Note that the file-extension might be used to infer additional information.