# Animated thumbnails for a video using FFmpeg 4.2.x

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm looking to accomplish as described in the accepted answer of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/538112/meaningful-thumbnails-for-a-video-using-ffmpeg/567297).

However, the command above no longer works in ffmpeg version 4.2.2.

I've updated the command to use the new format for applying multiple filters (comma separation), but getting the warning "Output file is empty, nothing was encoded" and there is no output.

```
$ ffmpeg -ss 3 -i input.mp4 -vf "select=gt(scene\,0.4), fps=fps=1/100" -frames:v 5 -vsync vfr out%02d.jpg
```

```
ffmpeg version 4.2.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.16)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.2.2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags='-I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-13.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/include -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-13.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin -fno-stack-check' --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41isomavc1
    creation_time   : 2017-01-14T09:24:55.000000Z
  Duration: 00:01:16.25, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 12030 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 2560x1440 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 11775 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-01-14T09:24:55.000000Z
      handler_name    : L-SMASH Video Handler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 256 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-01-14T09:24:55.000000Z
      handler_name    : L-SMASH Audio Handler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> mjpeg (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0x1191ca000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[mjpeg @ 0x7fd4e6806200] bitrate tolerance 4000000 too small for bitrate 200000, overriding
Output #0, image2, to 'out%02d.jpg':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41isomavc1
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: mjpeg, yuvj444p(pc), 2560x1440 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 0.01 fps, 0.01 tbn, 0.01 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-01-14T09:24:55.000000Z
      handler_name    : L-SMASH Video Handler
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 mjpeg
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x
video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)
```

Comment: Remove the fps filter, or set it to 1/15.

Comment: No output still, either with it removed or set to 1/15

Comment: Then the scene value is too high. Lower it till you get enough images.